# On button hover, enable ResizeMode

Tags: wpf

I am trying to make window frame appear when user hovers "mybutton". This should work but for some reason it is not. What am I missing?

```
<Window x:Class="test2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None"  Loaded="ShellWindow_SourceInitialized"   x:Name="mywindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">            
        <Style.Triggers>            
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=mybutton}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResize" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=mybutton}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="mygrid" Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <Button Name="mybutton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

(In case you are wondering what those "Loaded" functions are, they remove chrome while keeping the shadow and allowtransparency=false 
http://marcin.floryan.pl/blog/2010/08/wpf-drop-shadow-with-windows-dwm-api)
At the end it will not be button but will react on whole window border (I can not find better way to enable resizing while removing all chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myButton is defined after style. XAML parser is not that smart. User the following XAML to get your intended behavior:

```
<Window x:Class="test2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None"  Loaded="ShellWindow_SourceInitialized"   x:Name="mywindow">

    <Grid Name="mygrid" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" >
        <Button Name="mybutton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=mybutton}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResize" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, ElementName=mybutton}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

Comment: I just tested it. It works. There must be something else wrong with your? (OP?) code?

Comment: I tested it with a `CheckBox` `IsChecked` property binded to `mybutton` `IsMouseOver` property and it works fine even when the style defined above.

Comment: Thanks. This solution also works. I just did not anticipate that it would flicker like that.

Answer (score 2):

In the style TargetType should be MainWindow

<`Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">`
where local has to be mapped to your namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test2"
```

Comment: The target for the style is indeed important. vitaliy solution works as well. I hope someone tried the code before the negative feedback

Comment: Thanks. It works. I just did not anticipate that it would flicker like that.